# A corollary of Cauchy integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in an open region $D$ which is not necessarily simply connected, and $C$ is a closed rectiﬁable contour in $D$. Then $\oint_C f(z)dz = 0$
>   if either (a) $C$ is contained in a simply connected subregion of $D$, or (b) $C$ forms the oriented boundary of a simply connected subregion of $D$.

The part (a) is obvoiusly true by Cauchy integral theorem but I couldn't understand why (b) is true. How can we be sure that $C$ itself lies in simply connected subregion? I think it's a consequence of $D$ is an open region but I couldn't prove that.

Here is the source of the statement: http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/olver/teaching/MATH3964/cauchy.pdf

Comment: If $C$ forms the oriented boundary, are we assuming that $C$ is a Jordan domain? If so, you can at least solve the problem with Caratheodory's Theorem about Riemann maps extending by continuity to the boundary. It would surprise me if there wasn't a simpler solution, though.

Comment: Also, if $C$ is allowed to intersect $\partial D$, then, at the very least, we need $f$ to extend to $\partial D$ since otherwise, the integral doesn't make sense.

Comment: If $C$ forms the boundary then it is not necessarily included in $D$ so $f$ is not even defined on $C$, it doesn't even make sense to speak of the integral of $f$ along $C$...

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I took that paragraph from here: http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/olver/teaching/MATH3964/cauchy.pdf

Comment: @S.H.W regardless of where the paragraph comes from, the issue mentioned by both WoolierThanThou and me is indeed a conceptual problem that has to be addressed. Not necessarily by you, but by the ones who issued this poorly written problem text...

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I think $C$ is necessarily included in $D$. It's one of the assumptions.